# How to express `Class<? extends Any>`

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to write something like this:

```
var classList = ArrayList<Class<Any>>()
init {
    classList.add(ClassA::class.java)
    classList.add(ClassB::class.java)
}
```

That gets me errors like:

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Class<ClassA> but Class<Any> was expected
```

I can get rid of the error by doing an explicit cast:

```
domainClasses.add(NameIdMapping::class.java as Class<Any>)
```

That gets me an "unchecked cast" warning.  Is that the best I can do? How to do this cleanly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an `out`-projection: `ArrayList<Class<out Any>>`, this is mostly equivalent to a Java `? extends` wildcard.

See: [Variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) in the language reference.

Comment: Ah, that's it! I read the reference, but mistakenly thought "out" could only be applied at declaration, i.e. where `Class` is defined in this case. Thanks!